# Menu and content overlaps image in header

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a site banner above the menu on my site using a simple img tag but whenever I do so the menu just overlaps the image. What I want to achieve is the menu to be pushed down by the image above it so it appears right under it.

HTML:

```
<header>
<img src="site_logo.jpg" alt="">

<img src="banner_small.png" alt="" id="banner">
    <nav>
        <ul>
        <li class="selected"><a href="index.html">Main page</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="classes.html">Classes</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="gamemodes.html">Game modes</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

My first img is for the site logo and the second one is in the menu. I want to position the first img to be on top of the site and push the menu down

CSS:

```
header {
  height: 50px;
  background: #333333;

}
header nav {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
header nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#banner,
header ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
header nav > ul > li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 12px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just adding `margin-top` to the css for the menu?  Assuming the banner is always the same size then this should work fine.

Comment: Wrap your first image in a `div` tag. Also, you are colouring the whole header... so your first image will always "look" as if it is inside the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the images inside div elements:

```
<div id='x'><img src="site_logo.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div id='y'><img src="banner_small.png" alt="" id="banner"></div>
```

Then if you want to increse ou decrease the space between elements use the Margin property:

```
x{margin-bottom:...px;}
y{margin-top:...px; margin-bottom:..px;}
```